# How can i use pipe with argument in Linux/Unix-like

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, fzf

i want do something like that:

```
$ ( foo1.sh $1 | foo2.sh | bar.sh |) arg
```

sometime pipe is fast than write function, but i can pass `parameters/args` between pipe
now: I'm triad to search for package `firefox` by `xbps` but i get this error bellow:

```sh
$ xbps-query -Rs $1 | fzf firefox   

xbps-query: option requires an argument -- 's'
unknown option: firefox
```

Comment: Why not just `xbps-query -Rs firefox | fzf`?

Comment: because i use complex pipe (sed, awk...) and i don't want to back in middle to change args every time

Comment: This is a programming site. If you're asking about interactive use, [unix.se] is a better place.

Comment: yah, i think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipelines don't have arguments. Instead, write a script or function that takes arguments and runs the pipeline you want:

```
foo() {
  xbps-query -Rs "$1" | fzf
}
```

You can then run it with `foo firefox`

Comment: i don't want a function, but i search for something like `  xbps-query -Rs {} | fzf {firefox}` ,

Comment: You can do `bash -c 'xbps-query -Rs "$1" | fzf' _ firefox` but I have no idea why you would

Comment: yah , it's  work fine ^_^   @that-other-guy